# Why don't cellphones use unidirectional antennas?

Tags: electrical-engineering, wireless-communication

Why don't cellphones use unidirectional antennas instead of omnidirectional (single dipole) antennas?

This could be accomplished by using a unidirectional array of dipole antennas (specifically, a broadside array) placed at different locations in the phone, where each antenna's phase could be changed in such a way to minimize radiation directed into the user's head and maximize radiation sent in the direction of the cell tower, producing a radiation pattern as is shown in the picture below.

But, with digital electronics, arbitrary phase-delays could be introduced to change the orientation of the major lobe.

Cellphone batteries would last longer and there would be less adverse health effects due to EMF exposure.
[image: Unidirectional Array]

Comment: What if you be making a call and you suddenly turn around?

Comment: @fibonatic Many cellphones can already tell what direction they're oriented. They have built-in compasses and accelerometers. Changing direction would simply change the relative phases of the antennas such that the maximum power is always directed toward the cell tower.

Comment: And how does a cell phone "know" where the "best" tower is located? Is it going to save power to have a cell phone have a massive database of all tower locations, powers, and gain patterns and to combine that with an always on GPS for specific location? At any given time a cell phone could be in range of multiple towers.

Comment: _how does a cell phone "know" where the "best" tower is located?_ How they normally determine this. One dipole alone of the array suffices for that. Once connected to the tower, it could switch into unidirectional mode (i.e., use all the dipoles of the array).

Comment: Do you understand how physically large [such an array](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAVE_PAWS#Replacement) would have to be in order to be able to provide useful gain (directionality) in any arbitrary direction? I don't think you'd want to put such a thing in your pocket! And there would be no power savings -- the circuits needed to provide electronically-variable delays to such a large number of elements would consume far more power than the "excess" transmit power used with omni antennas.

Comment: @DaveTweed Your comment could be turned into an answer if you quantify it, explaining how such a small unidirectional array would require electronics with too small of a time resolution for producing the phase delays that it isn't practical with current electronic technology.

Comment: It isn't that there's a tradeoff between electronics and physical size. The physical size is set by the wavelength of the radio wave in question -- this is basic physics, and there's no way around it. And no, I'm not interested enough in the topic to work out the numbers.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, it's set by the wavelength, but it seems a directional array doesn't need to use full wavelength separation between the elements. For a cellphone, they might have to be something like, e.g., 1/64th of a wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **beamforming**, which exists in the 802.11 wireless standard.

Matthew S. Gast, [*802.11ac: A Survival Guide*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7461), glossary:

> Beamforming
> A method of using precise phase shifts on an antenna array that focuses the resulting transmission in a particular direction. Sending beamformed transmissions may require an exchange of control information to set up the antenna array.
>
> Beamformee
> The receiver of a beamformed transmission. The beamformee may need to transmit some packets in a beamforming setup exchange, but the main purpose of the beamforming exchange is to receive a directional transmission.
>
> Beamformer
> The sender of a beamformed transmission. The beamformer may need to receive some packets in a beamforming setup exchange, but the main purpose of such an exchange is to send a directional transmission.

[*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7461) Chapter 4. Beamforming in 802.11ac, § Beamforming Basics:

> [image]
>
> *Figure 4-4. Using multiple antennas to steer transmissions*

There is Single-User (SU) Beamforming and even Multi-User (MU) Beamforming.

Answer (score 1):

The answer when this question was asked was mostly size and cost of components and technical limitations around the size of the antennas and the limited space inside a phone.

Since then, the answer has changed, and modern phones do in fact use phased arrays.

Both WiFi 6 and 5G cellular chipsets support this, at least in some devices, and it's been supported on the access point side going back a generation or two.

And they do it for pretty much the reasons you laid out, since while consumers may not think overly much about the radiation from their phones, they do consider the battery life. And minimizing energy used to transfer data does improve battery life and reduce overheating.

The tradeoff is that there are some angles where your phone really will get a much worse signal depending on a few other factors like the number of available access points and the signal strength / signal to noise ratio.